# What's up with this room being gallery again?

Tags: discussion, chat

> This room is for discussions about Android. This is now a Gallery room, request write permissions and you'll be permanently granted with write permissions as long as you play by the rules. For rules, read pinned messages.

So ... what? I'm confused. Does this violate the concepts of the Gallery room, to make it a public club that only certain people can talk in there?

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android

Comment: There were [three users banned there earlier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92488/what-are-the-different-types-of-reasons-for-banning-a-particular-user) - I guess it's until that blows over.

Comment: @Rup I was well aware of that, I mean that the actual room just doesn't seem to warrant the behavior that exists there now. I won't even go into the fact that there are nine chatrooms targeting Android development, which is just a silly number to have. At least three of those should be merged. I haven't fully evaluated all of them, as I don't have those privileges there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is like that because of a certain reason. The reason is quality issues. People constantly jump in and ping everyone in the room with the ever same question. Most of the times they don't even post their question on SO.

This issue has been discussed here on meta a few months ago with the result to try the gallery room feature. If you want to know more about that just read my [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78334/how-can-i-improve-my-chat-rooms-quality) about it here on meta.